# How do i get an object of a response which is an empty string instead of an object when it doesnt exist?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

im trying to get an optional parameter which is

```
"attached_image": "",
```

when its not available and

```
        "attached_image": {
            "url": "https:\/\/img.devrant.com\/devrant\/rant\/r_6336983_TJuFZ.jpg",
            "width": 799,
            "height": 450
        },
```

when its available

When i set the type to my custom Object with url/width/height, i get the error:

```
MyCustomObject myCustomObject;

public String getMyCustomObject() {
    return myCustomObject;
}
```

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line...

when i set to type String like:

```
String attached_image;

public String getAttached_image() {
    return attached_image;
}
```

i get:
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line

Because obviously for the ones who are available it works and for the ones who arent, it doesnt.

Is there a way for it to just ignore and dont throw an error if its not the Object so i can check if its null?

Comment: Why not set it to null explicitly? `"attached_image": null`

Comment: I don't think you can do this in Java/GSON because those are two different types.  You have to pick one type and stick to it.  (Java, unlike some other languages, is strongly typed.  You can't pull off some of the tricks you are used to from those languages.)  I'd picked the second JSON example and use that, just allow the object to be `null` if that's what it is.

Comment: because i dont own the api lol

Comment: https://www.devrant.io/api/devrant/rants?app=3 this is the api. as u can see for some it "" and for some images and object